# What does these javascript expressions mean?

Tags: javascript, expression

These are pieces of code from a plugin that I'm trying to learn from. The variables are refactored to minimize file size thus become unmeaningful.

```
function sort(b) {
            for (var d = [], c = 0; c < this.gs.length; c++) for (var g = 0; g < this.gs[c].length; g++) d.push(this.gs[c][g]);
            b && d.reverse();
            return d
}
```

I'm assuming this sort function takes in either undefined, or some parameter for b, and returns an 2d array.

What does the b && d.reverse() mean? Does it mean if b has a value, reverse d?

The other expression is:

```
b = this.sort(g == "left" || g == "top");
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

> What does the `b && d.reverse()` mean?  Does it mean if `b` has a value, reverse `d`?

Correct. It's the *smart-ass* version of writing

```
if (b) d.reverse();
```

`reverse()` is an in-place operation, so it changes the array it operates on (hence the code does not care for its return value here).

The other statement works in a similar way:

```
b = this.sort(g == "left" || g == "top");
```

Evaluation begins with `g == "left" || g == "top"`. This yields `true` or `false` depending on the value of `g`. The result is passed to `sort()`, whose return value is then stored in `b`.

Answer (score 0):

b && d.reverse() means that if b isn't false, null, undefined or 0, then d.reverse() is executed. In other words: if we don't pass any argument (b) for the function or we pass false / 0, then d.reverse() doesn't get executed.

Second expression just passes either true or false to the sort() method. It's just normal OR operation where g has to be "left" or "top".